# LibGit2Sharp - List of outgoing and incoming commits

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I'm trying to find a simple way to find outgoing commits (where I've commited locally but still need to PUSH) and incoming commits (where I've done a fetch and found there are commits on the remote but I haven't PULLed them in to my local copy yet).

Diff almost did what I wanted, but I just want the total count of commits, not each file (ex 2 outgoing commits, not 18 modified files).

What's the best way to do this in LibGit2Sharp, please?

```
foreach (Repos r in config.Repos)
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(r.LocalPath))
    {
        foreach (StatusEntry statusEntry in repo.RetrieveStatus())
        {
            ..... I'm able to find info about my local differences here .....
        }

        var headTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree;
        var remoteMasterTree = repo.Branches["origin/master"].Tip.Tree;
        var diffs = new Dictionary<ChangeKind, int>();
        foreach (TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChange in repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(remoteMasterTree, headTree))
        {
            ..... this is giving me each file, but I only want "2 outgoing commits" .....
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got it !

```
    public IEnumerable<Commit> GetOutgoingCommits(Repository repo, String branchName = "master")
    {
        var branch = repo.Branches.FirstOrDefault(x => x.FriendlyName == branchName);

        if (branch.TrackingDetails.AheadBy != null)
        {
            foreach (var commit in repo.Commits.Take(branch.TrackingDetails.AheadBy.Value))
            {
                yield return commit;
            }
        }
    }
```